# Nested callbacks in asynchronous JS

Tags: javascript, callback, nested

I just started learning asynchronous features of Javascript and encountered what others referred as callback hell. Can someone offer some thoughts on the following way of handling nested callbacks. Are there possible, problems or drawbacks of this method.

Let say, I want to randomly generate a number, asynchronously. Then, modify the generated number via functions.

```js
function delayedFunctionalites(wait, ...funcs) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(`randNum is ${randNum}`);

    let updatedRandNum = funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), randNum);

    console.log(`updatedRandNum is ${updatedRandNum}`);
  }, wait);
}

const addOne = (input) => input + 1;
const multBy2 = (input) => input * 2;
const addFive = (input) => input + 5;

delayedFunctionalites(2000, addOne, multBy2, addFive);

// Output: randNum is 8
// Output: updatedRandNum is 23
```

Comment: What kind of thoughts are you wanting? The provided code doesn't seem to have badly nested callbacks?

Comment: You don't have nested callbacks. You just have one async callback, and it calls all the functions synchronously.

Comment: You guys are right. I have the wrong mental model of the problem.

Comment: There already is a solution to callback hell and it's promises.

Comment: Also `funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), randNum);` is functional composition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got some good insight from the comments, but for completeness, here's some different ways you can do promise chaining.

##### Test Function

This function adds 4 to a number after a 1 second delay. This is used in the examples below.

```js
const testFunction = async (input: number) => {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(input + 4);
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

### Call `.then()` Over and Over

This is the way you normally chain promises together. Each one comes after the next and uses the result of the one before.

```js
const callbackChaining = async () => {
    const value = 5;
    console.log('Value is', value);
    const result = await testFunction(value)
        .then(async (result) => {
            console.log('Value is', result);
            return testFunction(result);
        })
        .then(async (result) => {
            console.log('Value is', result);
            return testFunction(result);
        })
        .then(async (result) => {
            console.log('Value is', result);
            return testFunction(result);
        });
    console.log('Result is', result);
};
```

### Use a `for` Loop with `await`

You can use a normal loop with `await` to just get the result of each operation and then call the next operation on it.

*Note that there is an eslint rule that warns against not using `await` in a loop, so you will want to look into that to see if it's relevant to your situation.*

```js
const forLoop = async () => {
    let value = 5;
    const operations = [testFunction, testFunction, testFunction, testFunction];
    for (const operation of operations) {
        console.log('Value is', value);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        value = await operation(value);
    }
    console.log('Result is', value);
};
```

### Use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

You used `reduce` in your question. Here is a similar way of using it that can chain the results of a list of promises together.

```
const arrayReduce = async () => {
    const value = 5;
    const operations = [testFunction, testFunction, testFunction, testFunction];
    const result = await operations.reduce(async (result, operation) => {
        return result.then(async (value) => {
            console.log('Value is', value);
            return operation(value);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(value));
    console.log('Result is', result);
};
```